# ActiveAdmin: how to have a text field instead a color picker to input a color?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Picture a rails app with a `Flower` model. The `flowers` table has a `color` column. This app uses ActiveAdmin. In the admin layer, I register the the `Flower` model.

`app/admin/flower.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Flower do
  permit_params :color
end
```

If I edit an existing flower (or create a new one), ActiveAdmin will force me to edit the color with a color picker. I want to edit the color with a text field.

How should I go about it ?

I use Rails 4.1.4 and ActiveAdmin 1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override the form

```
  form do |f|
    inputs 'Details' do
      f.semantic_errors
      f.input :color, as: :text
    end

    f.actions
  end
```

For more information, please look at https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html

Comment: For the sake of completeness, `as: :text` will make it a `<textarea>`. Use `as: :string` if you want a `<input type="text">` instead.